# Restart xfce from tty1

Tags: xfce, tty

I am new to xubuntu, somtimes my xfce desktop crashes, and I can only use tty1 from command line.

I want to know how can I restart my xfce in tty7 from tty1?

I've googled it, but didn't found the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try killing user by

```
pkill -KILL -u yourusername
```

This will bring you back to login screen though.

Comment: Sometimes lose current windows is not a choice :X, u can do same restarting ldm service ( or the login manager you have ). Killing every process of a user it's the last option, because you may be working on tty1 and you will kill it too. Login manager (wich is x based) would not close other sessions.

Answer (score 26):

For me `startxfce4` didn't work, but `pkill` did.

You could try the following command:

`xfwm4 --replace`

It restarts the windows manager.

Comment: Yeah. This is, first try to reload window manager, if don't work try restarting login service, and in the worst of cases, kill your user then start again your work :)

Comment: Exactly. Don't forget to append a &:

xfwm4 --replace &

Answer (score 22):

`pkill` worked but seemed a little extreme to me. If I had other stuff going on in other tty sessions, it would kill those too.

Another solution is:

```
sudo systemctl restart lightdm
```

A great strength of Linux is that there are always multiple ways to achieve the same task.

Comment: --replace does try to save things :)

Comment: Ubuntu16 use `sudo service lightdm restart`.

Comment: I didn't try `pkill`. When I tried `xfwm4 --replace` (from other answers), it threw a GTK3 error from the command line. I tried this, and it worked great. Thanks Alan.

Comment: it somehow exited my running apps

Comment: Beware: `systemctl restart lightdm` kills the session and logs you out.

Comment: Both the `systemctl` and `service` commands fail with the error "Unit lightdm.service not found". What's wrong, please? I've installed the Xfce using apt (`apt install xfce4`).

Answer (score 10):

You can try `startxfce4`.

As [this](http://xfce.wikia.com/wiki/Tips,_Tricks_and_Howtos) site says:

> Restart XFCE4 : from the command line, you would better use
>   "startxfce4" to bypass stupid distribution X startup scripts that can
>   drive you crazy, really.

Comment: That's the start XFCE4, not to to restart it. When I ran `startxfce4` I got these messages:

/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :0.0
xfce4-session: Another session manager is already running

Comment: I get "xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused"

Comment: good luck fixing login loop afterwards: https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/308869

Comment: @Enkouyami well, when something crashes *Restart = Start*. You got the message `already running` because your `xfce4` **was not** crashed ;)—this is a linguistic issue. Anyway, this answer fits the question. :)